# Matrix printer only receives ~one character when SEL is pressed

Tags: linux, printer, parallel-port, dot-matrix-printer

I'm trying to get an OKI microline 3390 to work, and manually sending text to it as demonstrated here: [(thirty-minute video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5B1gz8TBiU). I understand the printer has to be selected for it to work, which on my model is labelled SEL. An indicator light comes on when I press it.

The printer has a mode to print a hex table of the characters coming in. When I send a string of characters to it, it will print only the first. When I then press the SEL button twice, once to deselect, and then to select again, the second character is written. I can repeat this process to have the hex codes of my entire string printed.
When not in hex dump mode, I can send the string to the printer, and nothing will happen. If I then push the SEL button as many times as the string has characters times two (select, deselect), it prints in full.

The printer is in epson LQ emulation mode.

How can I make it print without me having to press the button way too many times?